# Flutter - Unable to clear the cookie in Android inside the inappwebview

Tags: flutter, cookies, flutter-inappwebview

I am using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin to load the web app and am able to set the cookie. Whenever we try to clear the cookie on Android devices it's not clearing the previous one but it is removed on iOS, which results in two cookies on Android. The original cookie’s domain which is set from Flutter is getting prepended by a `.` (dot). Not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We face the same issue. I can't tell you why this was implemented, but I followed it inside of the Android CookieManager. The `.` is prepended in this line: [CookieManager.java - Line 964](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2269d1572e5fcfb725ea55f5764d8c3280d69f6d/core/java/android/webkit/CookieManager.java#964). 
The matching (if the cookie already exists) does not reflect that there could be one without the dot, see `CookieManager.java - Line 162`. This results in two equal looking cookies being created.

Comment: What is the solution to avoid this?